# How to send content of an existing HTML file as is into email body in java

Tags: automation, report, cucumber

Is there a way that I can send an existing HTML file as is in email body using java?

Background - For my cucumber selenium automation test framework I am using Cucumber HTML Report to generate execution result. The report is generated as an html file in a folder for each run. The report contains tabular summary of execution. I want this report to be sent as a part of email body (and not as an attachment).

What I did so far - I tried using java mail api. I was able to send the html in email body using the typical java mail api code that's available on google. But the problem is that the email received is loses its formatting. Tables lose its borders and many other styles too. I tried using jenkins also but no luck couldn't succeed.

code snippet :

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Research\\CucumberHTML\\target\\cucumber-html-reports\\feature-overview.html")), writer, "ISO-8859-1");

    // creates message part
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setContent(writer.toString(), "text/html");

    // creates multi-part
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
    msg.setContent(multipart); // sends the e-mail
    Transport.send(msg);
```

[Actualreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yThEq.jpg)
[HowReportLooksWhenSentViaEmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qUG5.jpg)

Can any one please help or suggest a better solution in this regards?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins CI tool for building and running your tests suite and sending email with the report after the execution is finished. I believe this is a standard practice and Jenkins has all the plugins that enable this functionality and more.

Comment: Thanks. I could send email with jenkins too. But the problem is report generated has such kind of strucutre. Parent report folder > subfolders -- CSS, embeddings, fonts, images, js and then report html file. Now if i send this html file as email; file is sent but it loses all formatting perhaps formatting comes from the folders like css, js, fonts. Is there a way that the html file is read as is without losing the formatting and then sent? I could also send email with report as an attachment but I want report content in email body and not as an attachment. Any further help highly appreciated